# php artisan serve working but URL not working

Tags: php, laravel

I  installed xampp and laravel in my system and while connecting my project in command prompt it shows as "Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8080) started", whereas it is not launching the browser and I manually copy the link to the browser and it is not working and getting the below error. Please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsH5u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that you're trying to connect to a different port (8000 vs 8080). Try `http://127.0.0.1:8080` or `http://localhost:8080`.